# Javascript | Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'color' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, css, mouseover

I have an div which changes the css of elements inside it when hovered on/off.
However I get an error when I mouseover and mouseout, and the color is not changed (the error is in the title of this question)

Whats interesting is the first two changes work (changing the image and changing color of id 'ace_title' but the mouseover and mouseout of 'ace_feature' generates the error.

Below is my code and what I have tried:

```
<div class="service_level effect8" onmouseover="getElementById('ace_service').src='images/ace_hover.png';
    getElementById('ace_title').style.color='#2C81B7';
    getElementsByClassName('ace_features').style.color='#2C81B7';"
    onmouseout="getElementById('ace_service').src='images/ace.png';
    getElementById('ace_title').style.color='black';
    getElementsByClassName('ace_features').style.color='black';">

    <img src="images/ace.png" id="ace_service">
    <p id="ace_title">Ace Service</p>

    <img src="images/icon_tick.png" style="float: left; padding: 3px 4px 0px 15px;">
    <p class="ace_features">
        Outstanding IT Support
    </p>

    <img src="images/icon_tick.png" style="float: left; padding: 3px 4px 0px 15px;">
    <p class="ace_features">
        Outstanding IT Support
    </p>
```

Comment: `"document.getElementById('ace_service').src`

Comment: ``getElementById`` and ``getElementsByClassName`` are both functions of ``document``.

Comment: why don't you try to put javascript variable in var then apply .color

Comment: Please indent your code properly.

Comment: can you try in google crome developer tool. Try to alert getElementById('ace_title').style    . I think you will be getting a undefined there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('ace_features')
```

returns an array of elements or undefined

You should change your mouseover event rather to an external function, so you could iterate all the class names as such

```js
function onMouseOver() {
  document.getElementById('ace_service').src = 'images/ace_hover.png';
  document.getElementById('ace_title').style.color = '#2C81B7';
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('ace_features'), i, len;
  
  for (i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++) {
    elements[i].style.color = '#2C81B7';
  }
}

function onMouseOut() {
  document.getElementById('ace_service').src = 'images/ace.png';
  document.getElementById('ace_title').style.color = 'black';
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('ace_features'), i, len;
  
  for (i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++) {
    elements[i].style.color = 'black';
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="service_level effect8" onmouseover="onMouseOver()" onmouseout="onMouseOut()">

  <img src="images/ace.png" id="ace_service">
  <p id="ace_title">Ace Service</p>

  <img src="images/icon_tick.png" style="float:left;padding:3px 4px 0px 15px;">
  <p class="ace_features">
    Outstanding IT Support
  </p>

  <img src="images/icon_tick.png" style="float:left;padding:3px 4px 0px 15px;">
  <p class="ace_features">
    Outstanding IT Support
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

When you use `getElementById` you receive a one element, so it works.
When you use `getElementsByClassName` you receive a collection of elements (containing two elements in your case), so it doesn't work.

The following line should work:

```
getElementsByClassName('ace_features')[0].style.color='black'
```

but it would be much better to use a normal script blocks instead of inline

Comment: so, though you mention it will return 2 items, you are saying that only setting the single element should work?

Comment: I only say that if somebody wants set a property to all the elements in a collection, it's no way to do it rather than setting this property to each element in a collection.