# Uncaught TypeError Cannot set property 'top' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript file that is beaing loaded last. In the file this code is executed:

```
var x = document.getElementById("bildfram1").offsetHeight;

document.getElementsByTagName("header").style.top = "calc(x/2)";
```

But I get this error in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'top' of undefined

Any help on how to fix this!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript | Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'color' of undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30232423/javascript-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-set-property-color-of-undefined)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do querySelectorAll, getElementsByClassName and other getElementsBy\* methods return?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-getelementsbyclassname-and-other-getelementsby-method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) returns an HTMLCollection of elements (an array-like object).

For this reason, you are required to target specific index(es).

`document.getElementsByTagName('header')[0].style.top = "calc(x/2)"`

[calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) is an experimental technology. If all you have to do a simple divison, you should probably do it beforehand.

```
var division = val/2;
document.getElementByTagName('header')[0].style.top = divison + 'px'
```